# could not serialize an access because of a parallel update in odoo 13

Tags: odoo

i'm having this error when i try to generate missing terms in odoo 13:
psycopg2.errors.SerializationFailure: ERROR: could not serialize an access because of a parallel update. [image]

Any solution to this issue plz?. thank's in advanced

Comment: Please expand your question with like if you are upgrading any module or clicking some button or anything.

Comment: hi @Saumilgauswami, i installed french language and then i tried to generate missing terms, here i got this errors.

Comment: Hey, I tried same scnario in runbot.odoo.com and I get success in updateting general terms , In your case I think somthing up with your database or parallal updating process.try again and again if you fail then update your addons with odoo github.